# PHP Query doesn't return correct value

Tags: mysql

I have a table **veicoli** like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| ID  |   Modello |   Targa             |  Marca     |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1   |   IVECO   |   XA123WE            |  GRANDX    |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 2   |   IVECO   |   CF556XD            |  TOURS     |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 3   |   FIAT    |   AS332ZZ            |  Punto     |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

For each vehicle I have one or multiple **revisioni_veicolo** (the one with bigger date is the one I need to check if insurance is still active or not based on today date)

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID  |   veicoli_ID   |   DataScadenzaRevisione | EsitoPositivo  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1   |   1            | 2019-07-01             |        1
------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2   |   1            | 2020-10-01             |        0
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3   |   2            | 2019-11-25             |        1
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| 4   |   2            | 2018-10-20             |        1
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks on another post here, I implemented my code to search only for StatoUltimaRevisione = 1 (StatoUltimaRevisione is the value of EsitoPositivo grouped by veicoli_ID and related only to MAX DataScadenzaRevisione inside the group)...but with my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT veicoli.ID, veicoli.Modello, veicoli.Marca,
                t1.MaxDataScadenzaRevisione, t3.StatoUltimaRevisione,
                CASE WHEN t1.MaxDataScadenzaRevisione IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS RevisioneScaduta,
                CASE WHEN t2.veicoli_ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS RevisionePresente
FROM veicoli LEFT JOIN ( SELECT veicoli_ID, MAX(DataScadenzaRevisione) AS MaxDataScadenzaRevisione FROM revisioni_veicolo GROUP BY veicoli_ID) t1 on t1.veicoli_ID = veicoli.ID AND t1.MaxDataScadenzaRevisione >= date(NOW())
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT veicoli_ID, MAX(DataScadenzaRevisione) AS MaxDataScadenzaRevisione2, EsitoPositivo AS StatoUltimaRevisione FROM revisioni_veicolo GROUP BY veicoli_ID) t3 ON t3.veicoli_ID = veicoli.ID
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT veicoli_ID FROM revisioni_veicolo ) t2 ON t2.veicoli_ID = veicoli.ID
HAVING StatoUltimaRevisione = 1
```

I get always on my results veicolo with ID = 1. Why?

```
array( ....
  'ID' => string '1'
  'Modello' => string 'IVECO'
  'Marca' => string 'GRANDX'
  'MaxDataScadenzaRevisione' => string '2020-10-01'
  'StatoUltimaRevisione' => string '1'   <---------------WRONG!!!!!!!
  'RevisioneScaduta' => string '0'
  'RevisionePresente' => string '1'
```

ADDED Fiddle 2: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2e43c/5   veicolo with ID = 26 is incorrect... show ID 114 instead 143 and StatoUltimaRevisione not correct

Comment: Try to make a query that queries the table `revisioni_veicolo`, resulting in returning rows per `veicoli_ID` containing the most recent `DataScadenzaRevisione` (hint: groupwise max). Joining the `veicoli` should be easy then.

Comment: Tried: SELECT veicoli_ID, MAX(DataScadenzaRevisione) AS MaxDataScadenzaRevisione2, EsitoPositivo AS StatoUltimaRevisione FROM revisioni_veicolo GROUP BY veicoli_ID HAVING StatoUltimaRevisione = 1. I get wrong result also with this

Comment: Start with `SELECT veicoli_ID, MAX(DataScadenzaRevisione) AS MaxDataScadenzaRevisione FROM revisioni_veicolo GROUP BY veicoli_ID`, now you have the maximum date for each `veicoli_ID`. Try to join the `revisioni_veicolo` table to this result.

Comment: (SELECT veicoli_ID, MAX(DataScadenzaRevisione) AS MaxDataScadenzaRevisione FROM revisioni_veicolo GROUP BY veicoli_ID) t1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT veicoli_ID, EsitoPositivo AS StatoUltimaRevisione FROM revisioni_veicolo GROUP BY veicoli_ID) t3 ON t3.veicoli_ID = t1.veicoli_ID HAVING StatoUltimaRevisione = 1 i get syntax error

Comment: fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/622392/1   veicolo with id = 26 is not correct!

Comment: Fiddle 2: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2e43c/5   veicolo with ID = 26 is incorrect... show ID 114 instead 143